# How use Immediate number in AGAL

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, molehill, agal

For example, I want to output red color in fragment shader.

HLSL:

```
return float4(1,0,0,1);
```

asm:

```
def c0, 1, 0, 0, 1
mov oC0, r0
```

How to implement this in AGAL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mov oc, fc0
```

you have to pass in the red constant via:

```
context.setProgramConstantsFromVector(Context3DProgramType.FRAGMENT, 0, Vector.<Number>([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]));
```

unfortunately, you can't define a constant in agal.